# Rundeck-unable to copy script to Windows node-Host not found

Tags: windows, ssh, scp, rundeck

Configuration::https://1drv.ms/t/s!AizscpxS0QM4hJo9MJWA6CKzd1BOwQ (Kerberos authentication-domain user)

Can run command againts windows node,OpenSSH installed,manual scp copy works from linux to windows

```
scp somefile rundeck@test.com@WIN-II425CK1GMO.test.com:/C:
```

,public key authentication works without issues but when trying to run powershell script in Job getting:

```
TEST.COM@192.168.0.13
Script  Failed dispatching to node DC: [jsch-scp] Failed copying the file: TEST.COM@192.168.0.13
Execution failed: 55 in project windows: [Workflow result: , step failures: {1=Dispatch failed on 1 nodes: [DC: HostNotFound: [jsch-scp]


Failed copying the file: TEST.COM@192.168.0.13]}, Node failures: {DC=[HostNotFound: [jsch-scp] Failed copying the file: TEST.COM@192.168.0.13]}, status: failed]
```

My bet is it happens because 2 `@` but don't know how to bypass it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of WinRM, specified ssh authentication in `resources.xml`

```
<node name="dc" description="My windows" tags="node2" hostname="192.168.0.13" osArch="x86_64" osFamily="Windows" osName="Windows Server 2016" username="rundeck" ssh-key-storage-path="keys/Linuxtopic/server.1key" />
```

Removed domain part in username `(@test.com)` so `jsch-scp` wasn't confused with double `@`